# Multi-threaded file processing and database batch insertions

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, file-processing

I have an Java main application which will read a file, line-by-line. Each line represents subscriber data.

```
name, email, mobile, ...
```

An subscriber object is created for each line being processed and then this object is persisted in database using JDBC.

PS: Input file has around 15 million subscriber data and application takes around 10-12 hours to process. I need to reduce this to around 2-3 hours as this task is an migration activity and down-time that we get is around 4-5 hours.

I know I need to use multiple thread / thread pool may be Java's native ExecuterService. But I am asked to do a batch update as well. Say taking a thread pool of 50 or 100 worker threads and batch update of 500-1000 subscribers.

I am familiar using ExecuterService but not getting an approach where I can have batch update logic too in it.

My overall application code looks like:

```
while (null != (line = getNextLine())) {
    Subscriber sub = getSub(line); // creates subscriber object by parsing the line
    persistSub(sub); // JDBC - PreparedStatement insert query executed
}
```

Need to know an approach where I can process it faster with multiple threads and using batch update or any existing frameworks or Java API's which can be used for such cases.

Comment: Using multiple threads to read a single file will not improve performance,  In fact, it probably will worsen performance.  Most media cannot perform multiple reads simultaneously.

Comment: I guess reading the file can be done by the Main thread itself. After a line is read it can delegate it as a task to a ThreadPool and continue the same with next line. In my case worker thread will do object creation & persiting.

Answer (score 1):

`persistSub(sub)` should not immediately access the database. Instead, it should store `sub` in an array of length 500-1000  and only when the array is full, or the input file terminated, wrap it in a `Runnable` and submit to a thread pool. The `Runnable` then accesses database via jdbc like it is described in [JDBC Batching with PrepareStatement Object](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/preparestatement-batching-example.htm).

UPDATE

If writing into database is slow and input file reading is fast, many arrays with data can be created waiting to be written in the database, and system can run out of memory. So `persistSub(sub)` should keep track of the number of allocated arrays. The easiest way is to use a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) inbitialized with allowed number of arrays. Before a new array is allocated, `persistSub(sub)` makes `Semaphore.aquire()`. Each `Runnable` task, before its end, makes `Semaphore.release()`.